# How to copy an entire line which matches the string and paste right after it with prefix?

Tags: shell, text-processing

I am trying to search for a particular line in a file using `grep` command and I am successful doing that.

Now I want to copy the entire line to a new line right after the original line. In other words, the original line should be followed by the new line with same content with some prefix.

For example: Original data :

```
Apple 
Samsung
Nokia
HTC
```

Say if I want the new data to look like

```
Apple
Samsung
prefix Samsung
Nokia
HTC
```

Note: I have multiple patterns with `Samsung`, where ever I found that it should do the same.

I tried to `grep` and pipe with `sed` and I failed. Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks

Comment: `grep` means `g/re/p`, it's for finding strings that match a regexp and printing them, not for modifying anything, `sed` is best kept to just doing `s/old/new` on individual lines as after that it gets complicated and/or non-portable, and any time you need `sed | grep` or vice-versa you should be using awk instead for clarity, efficiency, portability, robustness, etc.

Comment: You should have included regexp metachars and potential partial match failures in your example. See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern). With  the posted example you'll get answers that work for that example but not other values you're likely to encounter in your real data.

Comment: Actually - I assumed given your subject line `How to copy an entire line which matches the string...` that you wanted to do a full-line string match but now I see in your comment you say `I have multiple patterns with Samsung...` so now I'm not so sure. Please fix your question to clearly state if you want to do a regexp or string match, and if you want to do full-line, full-word, or partial matching and make sure your sample input/output covers the cases where a false match is likely, not just one trivial sunny day case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this using `awk`.

Using your example here is one way to do it.

```
awk '{print $0} /Samsung/ {print "prefix " $0}' filename
```

Breaking down the statement for you:
`{print $0}` is to print the entire line

`/Samsung/ {print "prefix " $0}` says to print "prefix " followed by the entire line, but only if the line contains Samsung.

Comment: This would insert the prefix on each line _containing_ the substring `Samsung`, for example on a line saying `Not Samsung`.

Comment: It would print all lines and then also print another line with `prefix Samsung` directly following any line containing Samsung. I tested it and the output is exactly as the example requested.

Comment: The point is it'll print a line that **contains** Samsung, not just a line that **is** Samsung. It'll also fail if the line in question contains regexp metachars. You need to do `$0 == "Samsung"` (i.e. a full line string match) , not `/Samsung/` (i.e. a partial line regexp match). Getting the expected output from some sample input is the starting point to a solution, not the end point.

Comment: The question explicitly states that they have multiple patterns with Samsung and that wherever found they would like to do the same though. Saying `$0 == "Samsung"` would not follow that behavior. I see no issue with a partial line regexp match because of this. I do see your point about the regexp metachars though.

Comment: No problem, I just posted my own answer.

Answer (score 3):

```bsh
sed -n 'p;s/^Samsung$/prefix &/p' file >newfile
```

This first outputs the current line.  It then substitutes the string `Samsung` with `prefix`, a space, and the matched string (which is what `&` will expand to in the replacement string), effectively inserting the string `prefix` in front of `Samsung` on each line that is `Samsung` only. If the substitution succeeds, the modified line is printed, creating an additional new line in the output.

The output is then written to a new file, `newfile`.

If you want to relax the matching of the string `Samsung` so that it matches anywhere on the line, then use, for example,

```bsh
sed -n 'p;s/.*Samsung/prefix &/p' file >newfile
```

---

Using `awk` to implement the equivalent of the above:

```bsh
awk '1; /^Samsung$/ { print "prefix", $0 }' file >newfile
```

The lone `1` is a short-cut way of writing `{ print }`, which in turn is the same as `{ print $0 }`, which outputs the current line.

Use just `/Samsung/` to match the string `Samsung` anywhere on the line rather than requiring that the line is just that string.

Obfuscated variant of the `awk` command above:

```bsh
awk '1; /^Samsung$/ && $0 = "prefix " $0' file >newfile
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a solution using GNU `sed`. It finds the string "Samsung" and replaces with itself and adds a new line with the matched pattern "Samsung", adding at the beginning of it "prefix ":

```bsh
# doubled the example data to show it works on every line
$ sed 's/^Samsung$/&\nprefix &/' file
Apple 
Samsung
prefix Samsung
Nokia
HTC
Apple 
Samsung
prefix Samsung
Nokia
HTC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{print} $0=="Samsung"{print "prefix", $0}' file
Apple
Samsung
prefix Samsung
Nokia
HTC
```

With a more comprehensive test case, imagine trying to duplicate the line `test.*` in this input file:

```
$ cat file
Apple
the testing regexp match failure case
Samsung
the test.* partial string match failure case
Nokia
test.*
HTC
```

So in the output only that 2nd-last line of `test.*` should be duplicated. My script does a full-line string match and so there's no problem, it only duplicates the one line that is exactly the string `test.*`:

```
$ awk '{print} $0=="test.*"{print "prefix", $0}' file
Apple
the testing regexp match failure case
Samsung
the test.* partial string match failure case
Nokia
test.*
prefix test.*
HTC
```

Try that same case with the other solutions you have.

If you do want to do a partial string match then you may want:

```
awk '{print} index($0,"Samsung"){print "prefix", $0}' file
```

but that would match "Samsungtheblues" which may or may not be what you want so I'll wait for you to clarify your requirements and provide a better example before making any further suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Another sed implementation, using the "hold space"

```bsh
sed '/Samsung/ {h; s/^/prefix /; H; g;}' file
```

Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Other-Commands.html

Answer (score 0):

Using POSIXly sed we can double the line by storing in hold but appending to pattern space only for `Samsung` lines. Then we place a prefix right after the newline separating the duplicated (`Samsung`) lines. For the others, the newline wouldn't show up so the substitution won't happen and sed will print the pattern space unchanged.

```
sed -e '
  h;/Samsung/G
  s/\n/&prefix /
' file
```

---

Another way is to first print the pattern space for all lines. And then , only for `Samsung` lines, prefix and print them.

```
sed -ne '
  p
  /Samsung/s/^/prefix /p
' file
```